# copy a file from multiple directories and add numbers in the prefix of each file?

Tags: shell-script, file-copy

I need to copy a particular named file from multiple directories and need to add number in the file prefix sequentially. For example I have the following directories, `gene1, gene2, gene3 ..... gene100` and each directory having a file namely `protein.fasta`. I need to copy all the `protein.fasta` file from each directory and paste in another directory namely output. 
I have tried the following script but the script is not serving my purpose, It copy and paste only one file and rest is not copied and renamed finally end up with error. Kindly help me to do the same.

```
a=1
for i in **/protein.fasta
do
cp "$i" "$a"_"$i" output/
a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

Detailed example and expected output is given below,
Directories

```
gene1, gene2, gene3....gene100
```

file to be extracted from each file is `protein.fasta`

Expected output in the `output` directory

```
1_protein.fasta
2_protein.fasta
3_protein.fasta
.
.
100_protein.fasta
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to loop over *directories* and remove the `gene` prefix from the current directory name to use as the prefix for the target file name:

```
for d in gene*; do 
  echo cp "$d/protein.fasta" "output/${d#gene}_protein.fasta"
done
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you want to use `basename` to remove the directory from the filename?

```
i=1
for f in **/test.file; do
  cp "${f}" "out/${i}_$(basename $f)"
  (( i += 1 ))
done
```

Comment: This won't prepend each file with the appropriate number though.  For example gene10 will be the 2nd result so `protein.fasta` from the `gene10` directory will become `2_protein.fasta`